# Getting the location of value from numpy.where() as single value and append it to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array in python created from numpy as:

```
a = [[1.         0.5        0.3 ... 0.71     0.72     0.73]
     [0.         0.4        0.6 ... 0.74     0.75     0.76]
     [0.         0.3        0.  ... 0.72     0.73     0.74]
                                ...
     [0.         0.2        0.3 ... 0.56     0.57     0.58]
     [0.         0.1        0.3 ... 0.67     0.68     0.69]]
```

and another array

```
b = [[1.         0.5        0.6 ... 0.74     0.75     0.76]]
```

which i got from `np.max(a, axis=0)`. Now I need the index of the array where the value in array **'a'** is equal to the corresponding value in **'b'** for which i used:

```
locn = []
for i in range(0, len(b[0])):
    for j in range(0, len(a)):
        fav = np.where(a[j][i] == b[0][j])
        locn.append(fav)
print(locn)
```

I get the output as

```
[(array([0]),), (array([0]),), (array([0]),), (array([0]),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([], dtype=int64),), (array([0]),), (array([0]),), (array([0]),), (array([0]),), (array([], dtype=int64),), ............
```

I could have used **np.where(a == np.max(a))** to get the location on maximum, but that is not my problem. I need the exact location (like 1st element of 1st array.. or something like that) append the index of array in loc[]. For example: for the first round 1 is the highest, i just need to **append the index value 0** to a **new list locn[] as 0** is the index for first round where the element of inner array is equal to the maximum value.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `argmax` instead of just max. For example

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 5))
```

> [
> [8 9 6 4 7]  
> [6 4 0 3 6]  
> [7 5 9 1 6]  
> [1 4 8 8 9]
> ]

```
np.max(a, axis=0)
```

> array([8, 9, 9, 8, 9])

```
np.argmax(a, axis=0)
```

> array([0, 0, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)

---

If you want to print the info the way you are describing then you can do

```
b = np.argmax(a, axis=0)
print('locn'+str(b))
```

> locn[0 0 2 3 3]

Comment: Please edit to show what values of `a` your example is working with, otherwise it makes little sense...

Comment: Thank you. i want the locations as in **locn[0, 0, 1, ... , 1, 1, 1]**. Can i get just the location and not the values. And why is it showing dtype? Has it got something to do with float?

Comment: `dtype` shows you the type of the data that is stored in the list. You can set that to anything you please. If you want to print it the way you are saying you can do `b = np.argmax(a, axis=0)
print('locn'+str(b))`.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I need. **argmax** game me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the to find elements are not the maxima but for example randomly chosen, we can still use `argmax` on `a==b`.

Example:

```
# generate random data
>>> n = 10
>>> a = np.round(np.random.random((n, n)), 1)
>>> a
array([[0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.1],
       [0.7, 1. , 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 1. , 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.5, 1. , 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4],
       [0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0. , 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6, 0. , 0.1],
       [0.4, 0. , 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0. , 0.6, 0.6, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3],
       [0.9, 1. , 0.8, 0.8, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5],
       [0. , 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.9],
       [0.8, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7, 0.1, 0.8, 0. , 0.9, 0.8]])
# randomly pick an index each column
>>> choice = np.random.randint(0, n, (n,))
>>>
# retrieve values at chosen locations 
>>> b = a[choice, range(n)]
>>> b
array([0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6, 0.5])
>>> 
# now recover `choice`, or if the same as the chosen value occurs 
# earlier in that column return the index of the first occurrence.
>>> recover = np.argmax(a==b, axis=0)
>>> recover
array([4, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
>>>
# check result:
>>> recover <= choice
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
>>> a[recover, range(n)] == b
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

As a nice little bonus this takes advantage of the fact that `max`/`argmax` short-ciruits on booleans (`a==b` is, however, still evaluated everywhere):

```
>>> timeit('np.argmax(x)', globals={'np': np, 'x': np.ones(1000000, bool)}, number=100000)
0.10291801800121902
>>> timeit('np.argmax(x)', globals={'np': np, 'x': np.zeros(1000000, bool)}, number=100000)
4.172021539001435
```